# How to redirect my Windows Phone C# app to a setting page?

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone-8, settings

I need an Method or Class that redirects my app to a setting page like "Ringtones+Sound" or "Brightness". I was thinking of something like "ConnectionSettingTask" class and ".Show()" method that redirects to a "bluetooth" page, for example. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701476) to open up built-in apps.
Use following code to achieve your requirement:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-bluetooth:"));
```

The problems: There are only limited uri schemes available. Here is a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and it's only available on Windows Phone 8

Comment: So, there is no way to create a program that changes screen brightness or redirects the user to brightness settings or to change Ringtones or its volume??

Comment: As far as I know ConnectionSettingsTask and LaunchUriAsync are the only ways to open up settings, and as long as those don't support those setting pages there is no way

Comment: I was searching a little bit and found URI for some nokia applications. What if "ringtones+sound" or "bright" are actually nokia apps (List: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List) ? I didn't found URI for the apps I want, but i think that they might be accessible, I just need to know how.