# Navigating to phone settings

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to navigate to phone settings page on tapping a button in windows phone?
I've a settings button, on tapping the control, the phone settings page has to be opened.

Comment: Did you search on Google before asking ?

Comment: I didnt find a solution.

Comment: I think [couple of first links](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=lC4lVNSEE6b8ygOG6IG4BA#q=open+settings+page+windows+phone+c%23) may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect my Windows Phone C# app to a setting page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685981/how-to-redirect-my-windows-phone-c-sharp-app-to-a-setting-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can open only a particular section of settings page. Try this:

```
    using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks; 

ConnectionSettingsTask task = new ConnectionSettingsTask(); 
task.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
    task.Show();
```

Ref: http://themagicsoftware.com/blog/2013/01/how-to-open-the-settings-screen-programmatically-in-windows-phone.html

Comment: I want to navigate to "phone settings" page, not the wifi setting page.

Comment: Then i think you can't do that. You can open a section but you can't open root page of settings